# How does difficulty level affect my exercise?

Tags: ring-fit-adventure

The difficulty level in Ring Fit Adventure can be set between 1-30. The games says my exercise will be tougher on higher difficulties, but the game doesn’t explain further.

How does changing the difficulty level affect my exercise?

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, it only seems to increase the amount of reps you do per set.  The game actually seems easier because you still seem to do the same damage per attack and you now do more attacks.  I cannot speak to the number of enemies since I increased my difficulty after every chapter and it seemed like the enemies increased from chapter 1 to 2 and in difficulty (different forms of monsters with higher stats) from 2 to 3.

To clarify some fitness jargon, the difficulty level influences the number of reps (times you do an exercise) per set.  By increasing the difficulty level, you will do more damage to monsters since you are adding additional attacks via more reps but the exercise will be harder since you have larger sets.  I'm assuming the game scales this way to make you more interested in being in shape since combat encounters will be harder on lower difficulty settings and you will need to spend more money on smoothies for health regeneration.

The long and short of it is the difficulty level only pertains to the exercise portion of the game.  The game difficulty and the exercise difficulty are inversely proportional from my experience with the game.

Comment: The damage increase of each individual attack is increased with level and new clothes but you also do more damage with the difficulty level since you are hitting more of each exercise per rep.  The only ones that have not increased are the yoga (green) moves so far.

Comment: The yoga exercises increase at higher difficulty levels. I started doing 8 rep while now I am doing 12 reps on the same exercise.